# Git different history on multiple remotes

Tags: git, git-remote

I'm using two remote servers.

Is it possible for create different history starting point?

For example:

`Remote 1: commit1 -> commit2 -> commit3 -> commit4`

`Remote 2: commit3 -> commit4`

In this case, I would like commit3 to be the history starting point on remote 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case you're describing, Repo 2 is a "shallow" repository.  If you have Repo 1

```
A -- B -- C -- D
```

then you can create repo 2 as

```
git clone --mirror --depth=2 --no-single-branch file://localhost/path/to/repo1 repo2
```

and now Repo 2 is

```
C -- D
```

In this repo you can see that `C` has a parent, and you can see the SHA ID for `B` listed as the parent of `C`; but commit `B` itself (and its history) is not present.

I used `mirror` because you described this as a second remote.  So this makes it bare and sets up the branches as local branches instead of remote branch refs.  You can create a shallow repo that isn't a mirror (with or without `--bare`), depending on your needs.  The real key is the `depth` argment.

By default `depth` only copies a single branch *and* configures the repo to only update that particular branch's ref on fetch.  `no-single-branch` restores normal behavior of mapping all refs.  That said, if there is a large or complex history in Repo1 then getting exactly what you want included may not be as easy as what I've shown here.

Note that if you use a local path, `depth` would be ignored; which is why I use a `file://` url above.

This is definitely a special case.  A commit's identity encodes its full history (which is one way to look at why `C` has to "know" its parent SHA ID), so generally having different histories would mean having different commits (that maybe happen to have similar `TREE`s) in Repo 1 than in Repo 2; so they could not coexist as remotes for a single, coherent local repo.  But in the specific case where you just want to exclude the earliest history up to a point, modern git provides this solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can't if you want to do it on the same local repository.

You can if you clone the repository twice. Keep your first clone for the first remote, the second clone will be for the second remote.
In the second clone, you'll need to rewrite history : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

That's the only solution I'm thinking of. You won't be able to have different history for the same repository (local/remote).